# Using speedtest or speedtest-cli on Pythonista

Tags: python, command-line, pip, pythonista, speed-test

I am trying to make an iOS shortcut that would notify me of the current internet speed. I thought of using speedtest module on Pythonista 3 by installing it using StaSh.

```
pip install speedtest

Querying PyPI...
Error: Version not found: speedtest
```

I don't know why that is, but I decided to use speedtest-cli instead. I know that works only through command line, but I still wanted to see something working. It was successfully installed, but whenever I tried to get the speedtest results, it said:

```
Package installed: speedtest-cli

speedtest-cli

stash: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'ShIO' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

How can I solve this? This is the first time I'm trying to use Pythonista.